# "lateinit" or "by lazy" when defining global android.widget var/val

Tags: android-studio, android-widget, kotlin

When defining a global `android.widget` variable, e.g. `TextView`, is it preferable to use `lateinit` or `by lazy`? I initially thought using `by lazy` would be preferred as its immutable but I'm not entirely sure.

`by lazy` example:

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    val helloWorldTextView by lazy { findViewById(R.id.helloWorldTextView) as TextView }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        updateTextView(helloWorldTextView)
    }

    fun updateTextView(tv: TextView?) {
        tv?.setText("Hello?")
    }
}
```

`lateinit` example:

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var helloWorldTextView: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        helloWorldTextView = findViewById(R.id.helloWorldTextView) as TextView
        updateTextView(helloWorldTextView)
    }

    fun updateTextView(tv: TextView?) {
        tv?.setText("Hello?")
    }
}
```

Are there any benefits of using one over the other when defining a global `android.widget` var/val? Are there any pitfalls with using `by lazy` to define a `android.widget` val? Is the decision just based on whether you want a mutable or immutable value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's one pitfall with `by lazy`. The widget property would be read-only and therefore *technically* final (in Java terms). But there's no documented guarantee that `onCreate()` is called only once for an instance. Also `findViewById()` could return `null`.

So using `lateinit` is preferable and you'll get an exception to tell you if the `val` was used before `onCreate()`.

A third possibility would be [Android synthetic properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html). Then you don't need to worry about the variables at all.

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

helloWorldTextView.text = "Hello?"
```

Comment: These are great points. Also, wow! That extension is amazing. Thank you for including it in your answer.

Comment: `onCreate(…)` is indeed called once per Activity instance, but the `lazy` delegate isn't tied to it anyway, it's just initialized when first called, which is perfectly ok in this case. Of course, synthetic properties are easier anyway

Comment: `lazy` can also cause a memory leak in `Fragment`s https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/kotlin-when-to-use-lazy-or-lateinit/

Comment: Late note: `lazy` delegate is a separate object which holds a noinline initializer lambda object and a lock object inside. It also involves some synchronization. Thus, `by lazy` is the most heavyweight option ever. But it's 2022 so everyone who still uses XML chooses viewBinding.

Answer (score 0):

**Here are some key differences between lateinit & by lazy**

- **var** is always used with **lateinit**.when you declare any variable with keyword **lateinit** then memory is allocated to that variable at the time of declaration
- **val** is used with **by lazy** which mean that a varable who is declared by lazy keyword will allocate memory when it will be used in **oncreate()**

Comment: This is wrong. Memory is allocated for all the “variables” (actually backing member fields) of a class when it is first instantiated, regardless of whether they use `lateinit` or `by lazy` or neither. In the case of `by lazy` a Lazy instance is also instantiated at that time.