# What is the best way to declare on UI component in android with Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to build android application using Kotlin for the first time.

I want to declare on some buttons outside the OnCreate method and i can initialize them only Inside this function with findViewById.

Can i declare in simple and clean code like in java?

```
private Button btnProceed;
```

Because when converting it to Kotlin it look like:

```
private var btnProceed: Button? = null
```

And then when initialize OnClick function need to add ! sign:

```
btnProceed!!.setOnClickListener
```

What is the right and cleanest way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["lateinit" or "by lazy" when defining global android.widget var/val](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056988/lateinit-or-by-lazy-when-defining-global-android-widget-var-val)

Comment: Hi Daniel, My question is more basic. You are right that the answers in your reference answering my issue, but if someone not familiar with lateinit or lazy (like i do) will not find this question like i didn't.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a good use case for [`lateinit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties). Marking a property `lateinit` allows you to make it non nullable, but not assign it a value at the time that your Activity's constructor is called. It's there precisely for classes like Activities, when initialization happens in a separate initializer method, later than the constructor being run (in this case, `onCreate`).

```
private lateinit var btnProceed: Button
```

If the property is read before a real value is assigned to it, it will throw an exception at runtime - by using `lateinit`, you're taking the responsibility for initializing it before you access it for the first time.

---

Otherwise, if you want the compiler to guarantee safe access for you, you can make the `Button` nullable as the converter does by default. Instead of the unsafe [`!!` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator) though, which the converter often uses, you should use the [safe call operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) where you access the property:

```
btnProceed?.setOnClickListener { ... }
```

This will make a regular call if `btnProceed` is a non-null value, and do nothing otherwise.

---

On a final note, you can check out [Kotlin Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html), which eliminates the need to create properties for your `View`s altogether, if it works for your project.

---

Last edit (for now): you should also look at using `lazy` as described in the [`other`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44286021/4465208) [`answers`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44286000/4465208). Being lazy is cool.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of using `lateinit`, you can also do [lazy initialization](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy):

```
private val button by lazy {
    findViewById(R.id.button) as Button
}
```

The first time you access the `button` property, it will execute the block once and use the result for future calls. In `onCreate` for example, you can now directly access it:

```
fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(bundle)
  setContentView(R.layout.my_view)

  button.setOnClickListener { ... }
}
```

Comment: This can cause a memory leak in Fragments. https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/kotlin-when-to-use-lazy-or-lateinit/

Comment: I try to use `apply` to setOnClickListener inside the lazy block `findViewById(R.id.button).apply{this.setOnClickListener{...}}` . But it does not work...But works inside onCreate. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`lateinit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties) as @zsmb13 suggest BUT this has the disadvantage that your views will be variable instead of final. If you want them to be final you can use the [`lazy` property delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy)

By using `lazy` you can declare how the value will be initialized when you first try to access it so by declaring

```
private val btnProceed: Button by lazy {
    findViewById(R.id.yourID)
}
```

Whenever you access your `btnProceed` you will have your activity (this example assume you're using an activity) loaded so you can use that method