# UNRESOLVED_REFERENCE in widget (TextView) resolved to error element in android-kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

How to update the text of Textview in kotlin. Set Text on-create function works but when I tried outside main fun it says unresolved ref.

How can I declare widget for reuse TextView for update the Text Value? 
I don't have exp with kotlin. Can somebody help me?

```
class MediaPickedActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val fullName = "Test User"
    var score = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_media_picked)

        val Tv_test = findViewById(R.id.tv_text) as TextView

        Tv_test.setText("$fullName :: $score ")

        if (score in 0..300) {
            score = 5
            setText()
        }

    }

    private fun setText() {
        // Error is here. I can't set text.
        Tv_test.setText("$fullName :: $score ")
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your `View`s as class level properties, and then you can access them from anywhere within the class. A variable declared inside a function is only accessible in that function.

```
class MediaPickedActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var Tv_test: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_media_picked)

        Tv_test = findViewById(R.id.tv_text) as TextView
    }

    private fun setText() {
        Tv_test.setText("$fullName :: $score ")
    }
}
```

I used `lateinit` in this example, but see a detailed discussion about different ways to declare the property [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44285703/4465208).

Comment: thanks   `lateinit var Tv_test: TextView`  it's works

Answer (score 0):

On top of what @zsmb13 said, you can also use the [Kotlin Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) plugin (since you included it as one of the topics) which is super convenient for minimizing potential `findViewById()` bugs, excluding the use of View fields/member variables, and etc. as follows:

> First apply the plugin in your local build.gradle file:
>
> `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`
>
> Next, import the widget properties for a certain layout in your Activity class:
>
> `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<layout>.*`

... and then your Activity would be as follows:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_media_picked.*

class MediaPickedActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val fullName = "Test User"
    var score = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_media_picked)

        // Simply references via the TextView's ID, and sets its text.
        tv_text.setText("$fullName :: $score ")

        if (score in 0..300) {
            score = 5
            setText()
        }

    }

    private fun setText() {
        tv_text.setText("$fullName :: $score ")
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also using a [lazy property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy) which will *initializing* the property **once** in needed and *separate* initialization from your logic, for example:

```
class MediaPickedActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val Tv_test by lazy { findViewById(R.id.tv_text) as TextView }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_media_picked)

        Tv_test.setText("$fullName :: $score ")
        // ...
    }

    private fun setText() {
        Tv_test.setText("$fullName :: $score ")
    }

}
```

**OR** write an inline function with a [reified type parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) `T` to makes the code more readable.

```
class MediaPickedActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val nonNull by find<TextView>(R.id.tv_text)
    val nullable by find<TextView?>(R.id.tv_text)
    // ...
}

inline fun <reified T : View?> Activity.find(id: Int): Lazy<T> {
   return lazy { findViewById(id) as T }
}
```