# Android kotlin butterknife view visibility

Tags: android, kotlin, visibility

I was trying to set the visibility of a view in android using [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) with Kotlin

I got the id in butterknife like:

```
@BindView(R.id.progress)
lateinit var progress: ProgressBar
```

The visibility can be set in Java like: (As we know)

```
progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I tried: `progress.visibility to .... ?`

How will it be in kotlin with ButterKnife?

Comment: "I tried: progress.visibility to .... ?". What did you try? You tried  `progress.visibility =View.GONE`?

Comment: @Raghunandan may be `progress.visibility= View.GONE `

Comment: Why are you using ButterKnife use kotlin synthetic instead. tutorial here: https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/

Comment: @Raghunandan yep, I tried same but it's not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
progress.visibility= View.VISIBLE 
progress.visibility= View.GONE
```

**Note**

You should use [**`kotlinx.android.synthetic`**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html).

> Every Android developer knows well the findViewById() function. It is,
>   without a doubt, a source of potential bugs and nasty code which is
>   hard to read and support. While there are several libraries available
>   that provide solutions to this problem, those libraries require
>   annotating fields for each exposed View.
>
> The Kotlin Android Extensions plugin allows us to obtain the same
>   experience we have with some of these libraries, without having to add
>   any extra code.

**Example**

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

    class MyActivity : Activity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            // Instead of findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progress)
             progress.visibility= View.GONE 
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried `progress.visibility= View.VISIBLE` but not worked, is it mandatory to use `kotlinx.android.synthetic`?

Comment: Thanx, I don't know why it's not worked before, I just restarted my studio `progress.visibility = View.VISIBLE` is made it work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same setters in Kotlin:

```
progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

You can also use a property access syntax instead, which does the exact same thing:

```
progress.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

---

As for the last part of your question, if you were trying to write this:

```
progress.visibility to View.VISIBLE
```

Then all that does is create a `Pair` which is never used and just thrown away - it's equivalent to this:

```
Pair(progress.visibility, View.VISIBLE)
```

Comment: As I said I tried `progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` but not worked, is it mandatory to use `kotlinx.android.synthetic`?

Comment: Thanx, I don't know why it's not worked before, I just restarted my studio `progress.visibility = View.VISIBLE` is made it work.

Comment: It's definitely not mandatory to use the Kotlin Android Extensions plugin by any means. It's just one of the available options (to see others, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44285703/4465208)). If you're comfortable using ButterKnife, you can absolutely keep using it with Kotlin.